# Can a SEPA direct debit be refunded in case of bankruptcy?

Tags: european-union, bankruptcy, direct-debit, sepa

Payments via SEPA direct debit (customer to business) can, in normal circumstances, be refunded unconditionally from the client's bank's website for eight weeks after the date of payment. Is this truly unconditional, even in case of bankruptcy? I'm asking because I'm afraid a supplier I deal with might go bankrupt, so I'm wondering if I can get my monthly advance back in that case, or if the SEPA direct debit refunds would be blocked and I'd go into the regular system behind all the preferred creditors. If it matters, both the supplier and I are in Belgium.

(I understand that I'd need to pay for the services delivered and I'm obviously willing to do that, this is not about that, only about getting the advance back for the services that were not delivered.)

Comment: I'm neither a lawyer nor familiar with relevant Belgian law, but in the Netherlands the _curator_ seizes control of all assets of the company as soon as bankruptcy is declared and nothing is allowed to be paid out without approval by the _curator_. Advance or no advance, it would be illegal to claw it back once bankruptcy is declared. I suspect it's going to be roughly the same in other countries as well, or management/owners could keep lots of money in flight as "advances" and then easily drain this money away before even the bankruptcy costs and preferred creditors get their turn.

Comment: @TooTea The thing is that I accepted SEPA direct debit payments for my own store, and when a client took their money back two months after a purchase, there was literally nothing the bank would do for us, except tell us to go to the police and report a theft. The refund was unconditionally accepted. Of course I wasn't bankrupt, so maybe the curator has some options us mortals don't have.

Comment: @TooTea I don't really get though how the fraud you describe at the end would work. SEPA direct debits are payments *to* the company. Why would management or the owners be paying the company instead of the other way around? Are you suggesting the owners of the company could do their entire initial investment using SEPA direct debit transfers that are cancelled and resent every two months? I'm pretty sure that's not legal and the notary will check that the investment money is in the company's account permanently.

Comment: There are 2 versions of sepa direct debit - one for customers (sepa core), and one between businesses (sepa b2b). Do you know which of those you use? Also, do you have a contract that you are supposed to make these payments (e.g. is the company entitled to that money?)

Comment: @Solarflare The one for customers. Your second question is a lot harder to answer. Yes, I agreed to pay these advances, but they agreed to refund part of it (or charge extra) based on the actual services that month. As far as I can see possession is 9/10ths of the law in bankruptcies in Belgium so I'm mostly wondering about the technical ability to get the money back. If it turns out later that they're legally entitled to get my money anyway, so be it.

Comment: That was just a wild theory of mine, feel free to ignore it. I was thinking about the typical case of related/sister companies invoicing each other for some services. If advances were completely protected from bankruptcy, that would be a great way to pull all the cash into one company,leaving an empty shell.